# Correct way to hide on load for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

So I have a form two two inputs, "Free" and "Price". Free is a checkbox, and if the box is checked then the Price box should not show, if it is unchecked then the price box should show.

I can easily hook the onChecked and toggle the visibility on and off after the page has loaded, but the question is pre-loading what is the best practise.

From what I can tell theres three main solutions here :-

1. Set an inline style to set the visibility based on the starting model, ie @(model.Free?"hidden":"visibile") this just seems sort of bad practise since isn't CSS supposed to be seperated from structure, this kinda mixes the two a little.
2. Set a jQuery handler to fire on load to check the checkbox status, the problem with this approach is that theres a few seconds before it fires so you get a "flicker"
3. Some other thing I'm missing...

Any advice?

Comment: Set a CSS class for all of these that has the style `display: none;` and then use your `ready()` function to show the ones you want.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, this can be tricky sometimes. I realize this is not part of the question, but some frameworks like the knockout visible binding only show/hide by adding/removing a display:none inline style. If you apply a class to hide initially, that visible binding would not work (without extra work during ready(), like you mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

Most css styles are better off separated into an external stylesheet, but for a simple `style="display:none;"`, inline styles are fine.

Also, as of MVC4, if a variable is null, Razor won't render the attribute.

```
@{
    var displayIt = Model.Free ? "display:none;" : null;
}
<div style="@displayIt">
    The above style attribute will not be rendered when displayIt is null
    (in MVC4)
</div>
```